# How to create square matrix of characters with random, letters a..z in C

Tags: c

I have started working in C language before few days. I want to create **square matrix of characters** with random, lower-case letters of a..z. 
Like:

a x r z
b q e s
w o t x
p y u o

How to create square matrix like this in **C language**. I have searched it but didn't get any solution. It will be helpful if any one can give me solution.

Comment: How far have you got?

Comment: Do you know how to create a 2D array (matrix) in C?  If so, why can't you create a square matrix?  Or can you create a square matrix but you don't know how to get random values into it?  Please clarify your question, and show what you've tried and highlight the problems with what you've tried.

Comment: Generate a number between 0 and 26, add `'a'` to it. Assign it to an element of the matrix. Repeat until matrix is filled.

Comment: I have created square matrix of  character. I don't know how to create random square matrix of character.

Comment: If you don't mind repetition just assign a random letter to each array element. Otherwise shuffle an array with all letters and assign the first N elements to your array.

Comment: @pmg Thank you for replying. Can you please give me code of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 4

void Init(char matrix[SIZE][SIZE])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
        for (j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = (char)('a'+rand()%('z'-'a'+1));
}

int main()
{
    char matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    Init(matrix);
    // The rest of your program...
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code given by @barak is absolutely working. I have added some code to print that matrix..

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 4

void Init(char matrix[SIZE][SIZE])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
    for (j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = 'a'+rand()%('z'-'a'+1);
}

int main()
{
    char matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
    int i,j;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    Init(matrix);
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        for(j=0;j<SIZE;j++){
            printf("%c",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `SIZE` for controlling the loops that print the array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all take into account that it is not necessary that all lower case letters follow each other without some intermediate symbols as for example in EBCDIC. So it is better tp define the corresponding sequence yourself.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void square_matrix_init( size_t n, char matrix[][n] )
{
    char *s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    const size_t N = 26;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) matrix[i][j] = s[ rand() % N ];  
    }
}   

int main(void) 
{
    size_t n = 4;

    char matrix[n][n];

    srand( (unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        square_matrix_init( n, matrix );

        for ( size_t k = 0; k < n; k++ )
        {
            for ( size_t l = 0; l < n; l++  ) printf( "%c ", matrix[k][l] );
            printf( "\n" );
        }

        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
p p g z 
c i v n 
v y n p 
w g x t 

w i e l 
l i c q 
u f y e 
d z t s 

o z t t 
i q i f 
q w v m 
c s h y 

a m k l 
w o e q 
t e v y 
d q s u
```

Comment: If OP wants to shuffle the array (or take unique values) he will need the slightly different `char s[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`